# Passing a variable from one controller to another and making if else conditions in regard to the value of that variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to pass a variable from one controller to another.

```
class CategoryController < ApplicationController
  def national
     @catid = Category.where(category_id: "1" ).select(:category_id)
     if user_signed_in?
        @news = current_user.news.build
        @feed_items = current_user.feed
      end
   end
 end
```

I have this variable `catid` in the `CategoryController` which I am trying to pass to `newscontroller`. And according to the value of `catid` that is generated in the respective action of `CategoryController`, I want to save news in `NewsController` and render it to layout. But I am not able to pass `catid` to `@news` object. And the `if` condition generates some kind of error like `"Template Missing"`. How can I solve it?

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :current_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

   def create
     if params[:action] == "national"    
       @news = catid.current_user.news.build(news_params)
       if @news.save
         flash[:success] = "News Posted"
         redirect_to root_url
       else
         @feed_items = []
         render 'category/national'
       end
     end
  end

end
```

Comment: You can't pass an instance or local variable directly from one controller to another; they're different objects. Perhaps you should include the category ID in a link on the page generated by CategoryController. As for your other error, please include it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing instance values between two different controller methods is not possible. They are meant to be associated with a specific route.

If what you want is to share some common methods between two different controller methods, you can place it in ApplicationController.